# Divide by zero error encountered - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, divide-by-zero, dateadd

I'm generating a random DateTime in SQL Server table using the following sample code

Sample Code:

```
DECLARE @SeedInt INT = 0;
SELECT DATEADD(minute,(-1 * (ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % (CASE WHEN @SeedInt IS NULL OR @SeedInt <= 0 THEN 2 ELSE @SeedInt END - 1))) + 1), SYSUTCDATETIME());
```

Its working fine. But I tried the same approach in an UPDATE Query, its failed to Update and throws an exception

Table schema: **StudentMark**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentMark]
(
    [StudentMarkId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [SubjectId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Score] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ScoreInfo] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [GeneratedOn] [datetime2](2) NOT NULL,
    [IsPass] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentMark] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentMarkId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample seed data

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[StudentMark] ([StudentId], [SubjectId], [ScoreInfo], [GeneratedOn], [Score], [IsPass])
VALUES ('FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581', '0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-10 10:10:15', 95, 1),
       ('0F4EF48C-93E3-41AA-8295-F6B0E8D8C3A2', '0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-10 10:10:15', 100, 1),
       ('0F4EF48C-93E3-41AA-8295-F6B0E8D8C3A2', 'AB172272-D2E9-49E1-8040-6117BB6743DB', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-16 09:06:20', 25, 0),
       ('FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581', 'AB172272-D2E9-49E1-8040-6117BB6743DB', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-16 09:06:20', 82, 1);
```

**Update Query**: (SQL Server)

```
UPDATE SInfo
    SET
        GeneratedOn = DATEADD(minute,(-1 * (ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % (CASE WHEN SInfo.StudentMarkId IS NULL OR SInfo.StudentMarkId <= 0 THEN 2 ELSE SInfo.StudentMarkId END - 1))) + 1), SYSUTCDATETIME())
    FROM dbo.StudentMark AS SInfo
```

But the query throws an exception

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
>   Divide by zero error encountered.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Kindly assist me whats wrong in the Query, what needs to do to fix this issue?

Comment: If StudentMarkId is one, you'll get zero when you subtract one. To fix, don't divide by zero. I can't begin to understand what that calculation is trying to accomplish, so I don't know exactly what would be needed

Comment: @Ghost - In my Sample code, I generated the `DateTime` using `DECLARE @SeedInt INT = 0;` Show how it will case an issue?

Comment: Set your seed value to 1 and you'll get the divide by zero

Comment: @Ghost - Yes you are right. Thanks alot...

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the `%` operand is 0.  So, use `NULLIF()`:

```
UPDATE SInfo
    SET GeneratedOn = DATEADD(minute,
                              (-1 * (ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % NULLIF(CASE WHEN SInfo.StudentMarkId IS NULL OR SInfo.StudentMarkId <= 0 THEN 2 ELSE SInfo.StudentMarkId END - 1), 0)) + 1)), SYSUTCDATETIME())
    FROM dbo.StudentMark SInfo;
```

Comment: Kindly check the query, it has a Syntax issue.